# Http request and response in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am currently working in codeigniter and I am new to this.
I was wondering how to retrieve the JSON values using API call .
Can anyone suggest me where should I start.

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: As in you are sending a request to code igniter, or want to send/receive between code igniter and an api?

Comment: I want to send and receive between codeigniter and an api. Request Response format should be json.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your array of row to  json_encode();example for method of controller is below

```
public function getUserList() {   
        header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
        $query = $this->db->get('mytable');
        if(count($query) > 0) {
            $message = array('status' => 'true' , 'message' => 'Record get successfully' , 'data' => $return );
        }else{
            $message = array('status' => 'false' , 'message' => 'Record not found.' ); 
        }
        echo json_encode($message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Codeigniter does not have an inbuilt HTTP method so you need to use other things in php to achieve this.

There are 2 ways, you can use cURL, but honestly... it's convoluted... but read this: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Another method is using `stream_context_create()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php

I strongly suggest using this 2nd one as its much easier to work with (in context with curl..

Much of how you setup your request depends on the API you are referencing with and the kind of requests it allows: GET, POST ... and what kind of header information it requires you to send over as well do they require oAuth header?

There is no 1 bunch of code fits all, I had to create a full custom library to integrate codeigniter into Magento, it took many hours.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestion.